# postfix backupmx and proxy_interfaces

Tags: proxy, backup, postfix-mta, mx-record

I have 2 mail server

mail1.domain.com    1.2.3.4
mail2.domain.com    1.2.3.5

I want mail2 to be proxy for mail1 and mail2 to be backup mx for mail1
Is this possible ?

I found in the postfix man the following :

> proxy_interfaces (default: empty)
>
> The network interface addresses that this mail system receives mail on by way of a proxy or network address translation unit. [...] You must specify your "outside" proxy/NAT addresses when your system is a backup MX host for other domains, otherwise mail delivery loops will happen when the primary MX host is down.
>
> ```
> Example:
>
> proxy_interfaces = 1.2.3.4
> ```

is this the setting I must supply to mail2 main.cf ?

Or do I need to say:

proxy_interfaces = 1.2.3.5 ?

I do not catch this exactly ......
What happens when mail1 goes offline ?

second question:
how do i transport the mails from the backupmx tp the main mx when the main mx goes online again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
proxy_interfaces = 1.2.3.4
```

because 1.2.3.4 is the proxy

mail mail go to mail2 and you will have to fetchmail it.

Comment: Correct solution. You know how also how to send mail over proxy like says this user? [https://serverfault.com/questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/1007682/postfix-over-proxy-like-socket-or-ssh-tunnel) on serverfault?